# Find the first minimal window of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an integer array, a window [a,b] is composed of elements of the array between a and b and the size of the window is b - a. Now your should find the first minimal window between which there are N/2 elements(N is the size of the array, b is bigger than a). 
For example {5, -3,10, 12, -2, -5}, we get the answer [-5,-2].

Comment: N is the length of the array. a and b is the elements of the array.

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? What should have worked? What didn't you understand? What did you understand?

Comment: I try to sort the array firstly with O(nlogn) and then find the minimal window with O(n). I just wonder is there a better method?

Comment: A typical 'Euler-problem' problem :-) Or Codility.

Comment: So the size of [-5,-2] is -2 - (-5) = 3? Wouldn’t [12,-2] with -2 - 12 = -14 be better?

Comment: Uhmm, I think the result must be zero or positive. Or nothing, of course.

Comment: How did you arrive at [-5,-2]? Wouldn't that contain 4 or 5 elements, depending on how you count, and since the entire array is 6, 6/2 should be 3.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it well, you have to find first window of length N/2, which has smallest sum.

You can achieve this by trying all possible windows of such a length and maintaining the smallest found so far. If you do this in a clever way, you can have O(N) complexity algorithm. As it seems to be a homework, I will let you figure it out yourself ;)

Comment: I'm though interested in how you can try all possible windows within O(N) :-)

Comment: All right then. You can compute the sum of the next window from the sum of previous window in constant time (add the last value of actual window and subtract the first value of previous window).

Comment: Computing the sum of first window is O(N) and the number of windows of fixed length is again O(N). Thus the result complexity is O(N) as well.

Comment: hint - you can use a sliding window algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:
a. Find out N (in O(N) time)
b. Traverse the array and for each element x<sub>i</sub> look up N/2 - x<sub>i</sub> in a hash/map. If found you have your solution otherwise insert N/2 - x<sub>i</sub> in the hash/map (O(n) time if using a hash or O(nlogn) if using a map and O(n) space).